# Typescript doesn't allow to use number/array in URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

The type of append method of `URLSearchParams` is `append(name: string, value: string): void;` in typescript.

I tried appending array & number it worked for me in the browser but gives error in typescript code.

In MDN I found an example where number is being used as a value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append

I want to know if we can use other than string as value in typescript

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: maybe he wants to know how to force ts to accept other values than string

Comment: you can convert the values to a string, or create some method overrides to handle the different input

Comment: @SandroSchaurer Maybe/Probably, but it's still better for them to ask, than it is for us to guess.

Comment: That's what TypeScript is for, it prevents stupid type errors. Arrays and numbers are not a part of an any URL, make an explicit conversion to string before assigning to another string.

Comment: If your happy with the browser auto boxing to a string, you could cast as a string.. `append(art as string)`. Although I think casting should be the last option, `toString` etc would be better.

Answer (score 6):

Typescript is there to prevent errors, that happen by mistakenly using the wrong type.

A URL is per default a single string, therefore the method only needs to accept a string.

Using typescript, you can just do the following to cast the number to a string:

```
const num = 1;
whatever.append('param', num + ''); // or call num.toString()
```

JavaScript (without the Typescript overhead), just converts the number to a string as soon as you append it to the whole URL. That is happening internally inside the `.append()` function (or maybe even later).

But in JavaScript you could also pass a variable of instance `Date`. It is possible, but the `.append()` function probably gets confused, throws an error, or calls the default `.toString()` of `Date` which you might not want.

Answer (score 2):

It works in browser because your browser is interpreting javascript code, not typescript. Typescript gets compiled into javascript code before being ran - you cannot run pure typescript. Try converting your array and number to strings before calling the append function, ie:

```
var name = [0,1,2]
var value = 3
name = name.toString()
value = value.toString()
x.append(name, value)
```